# vue.js get innerhtml from contenteditable element on input

Tags: contenteditable, vue.js

I'm trying to bind a vue.js event to detect a change on an element via contenteditable=true.

```
<div id="test" contenteditable="true" v-on-input="trigger" v-model="test"></div>
```

This triggers the trigger method in my vue.js vue, but I can't seem to grab the model value.

Does anyone know how I can grab the innerHTML/innerText after the input event?

Answer (score 9):

Okay short description:

Template:

```html
<div contenteditable="true"
     v-html="myHtmlCode"
     @input="onDivInput($event)">
</div>
```

Script:

```js
methods: {
    onDivInput: function(e) {
        this.myHtmlCode = e.target.innerHTML;
        console.log('Text: %o', this.myHtmlCode );
    },
},
```

Comment: At least in current vue and in at least some browsers, this falsifies "contenteditable" by apparently doing a circular update (first the handler updates the variable and then the `v-html` updates the content of the div in turn) with the unfortunate side effect that the cursor jumps to an arbitrary position resp. to the beginning of the div.

Comment: A workaround for most of cases is to listen to the changes on `blur` event instead of  `input`. this way you won't have the cursor jump and save changes once editing is done. But in the case you want the live update to change something else then this won't be enough.

Comment: I have done some experimenting regarding the cursor position of a live updating contenteditable. You can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/larsolesimonsen/w2cvpm9u/144/ Note that it has not yet been adapted to vue. That work is ongoing :)

Answer (score 7):

Solved it by using `event.target.innerText` in my vue.js component

Comment: can you provide a more detailed example of your component? are you using a watcher? or a computed property with getter/setter?

Answer (score 2):

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      content: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onFocusOut: function(e) {
      this.content = e.target.innerHTML
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" v-html="content" @focusout="onFocusOut($event)"></div>
```

Comment: It would be cool to add some pieces of information and details about what your code does and how it does it to help OP understand why your code could solve his issue.

Answer (score 1):

one line only
use @blur instead of @input

`<div contenteditable="true" @blur="test = $event.target.innerText">{{test}}</div>`